# C variable losing value when printed

Tags: c, variables, logic

Here is what is happening: I give the variable "pay" a value. 16 for example. I print pay using printf, and I get 16 back. I then print it again, and get 0. If I print it a third time, I get 16 again.

Also, no matter what I do I always seem to get 0 for employee type.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

float pay;

int employees;
int type;
int hours;
int items;
int i;
int j;

printf("How many employees? ");
scanf("%d", &employees);

float array[employees][2];

for(i = 0; i < employees; i++)
{
    printf("\nWhat type of employee is employee #%d?", i + 1);
    printf("\nEnter \"1\" for Manager.\nEnter \"2\" for Hourly Worker.\nEnter \"3\" for Commission Worker.\nEnter \"4\" for Pieceworker.");
    scanf("%d", &type);

    switch (type) 
    {
        case 1:
            array[i][0] = 1;
            printf("\nWhat is the weekly pay for employee #%d (manager)?", i + 1);
            scanf("%f", &pay);

            array[i][1] = pay;
            printf("\nEmployee #%d earned $%.2f this week.", i + 1, array[i][1]);

            break;

        case 2:
            array[i][0] = 2;
            printf("\nWhat is the hourly pay for employee #%d (Hourly Worker)?", i + 1);
            scanf("%f", &pay);

            printf("\nHow many hours did employee #%d work this week?", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", &hours);

            if (hours > 40)
            {
                pay = ((hours - 40) * pay * 1.5) + (hours * pay);
            }
            else
                pay *= hours;

            array[i][1] = pay;
            printf("\nEmployee #%d earned $%.2f this week.", i + 1, array[i][1]);

            break;

        case 3:
            array[i][0] = 3;
            printf("\nWhat were the gross sales for employee #%d (Commission Worker)?", i + 1);
            scanf("%f", &pay);

            pay = (pay *.057) + 250;

            array[i][1] = pay;
            printf("\nEmployee #%d earned $%.2f this week.", i + 1, array[i][1]);

            break;

        case 4:
            array[i][0] = 4;
            printf("\nHow many items did employee #%d (Pieceworker) produce this week?", i + 1);
            scanf("%d", &items);

            printf("\nHow much does employee #%d get paid for every item they produce?", i + 1);
            scanf("%f", &pay);

            pay *= items;

            array[i][1] = pay;
            printf("\nEmployee #%d earned $%.2f this week.", i + 1, array[i][1]);

            break;
    }
    array[i][0] = type;
    printf("\n\nEmployee type: %d", array[i][0]);
    printf("\nEmployee #%d earned $%.2f this week.", i + 1, array[i][1]);


}

printf("\n\nEmployee # | Employee Type | Weekly Pay");

for(j = 0; j < employees; j++)
{
    printf("\n%10d | %13d | $%.2f", j + 1, array[j][0], array[j][1]);
}

}
```

EDIT: Now I am able to get the value for pay printed. However when I try to print the employee type, I still get 0.

Also, the final loop that prints a chart is returning 0 on the two values still. Any ideas? (Code above updated)

Answer (score 3):

```
float array[employees - 1][2];
:
for(i = 0; i < employees; i++)
    :
    blah blah blah ... array[i][2] ...
```

You are accessing outside the bounds of your arrays.

When you define something like `array[42]`, the array elements are indexed by the values `0` through `41` inclusive. C uses *zero-based indexing.*

You seem to be overstepping the bounds in both dimensions, first by using `employees - 1` to create the first dimension, second by using `2` as an index for the second dimension despite the fact you should only be using `0` and `1`.

I'd fix up that undefined behaviour first before attempting to solve any other problems.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be array index is wrong and it starts from 0 but you have used 1 and 2